# Alternate phrase for "hold the main idea"

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

I'm finding words to replace "hold the main idea". It'd be used in the following examples.

> When running a project, the manager should always remind his/her team members to hold the main idea of it.

Or this

> Hold the main idea while drafting. Otherwise, you'd missed something important.

P.S. Maybe these are weird, but I'd be grateful if you edit my examples.

Comment: Keep the main idea in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to not lose sight of the original plan:

- **Stick to the plan.**

If you want them to keep focused on the objective/goal, you could try

- keep your **eyes on the prize**.

If you  want them to do only the basics and not add extraneous features:

- Remember this is a **no frills** {project}

Or if you know them well enough that they wouldn't be offended, try:

- Remember the **K.I.S.S**  principle — (Keep It Simple, Stupid)

Answer (score -1):

You may say that "team members must **focus on the essential**".

Comment: Why would one say that?